# Computer turns on and off slowly after adding ssd

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have and old PC with HDD. I replaced my DVD drive with caddy and added SSD. Then I reinstalled Windows 10 on SSD. So I have Drive 0 - HDD, and Drive 1 - SSD with Windows.
But now when I turn on my PC it shows BIOS screen for 30-60 seconds. Then windows loads within 5-10 sconds. Also, when I turn off it tooks again 30-50 seconds to power off.
What can be a problem? Can it be because of drives order? I installed Windows on the second drive (SSD), not the first one (HDD)

Comment: What happens when you disconnect both HDD & SSD and boot, does it clear BIOS stage quickly. There would be no OS to boot though. Most likely firmware is taking time to detect either of the two devices.  Try one at a time too and isolate the issue.

Comment: As I supposed the problem was in the drives order. I swapped SSD and HDD and it solved the problem. Now I have SSD with Windows as first drive and HDD as second,